# String Replacement in Program

Tags: string, perl

I have a perl script (new.pl) that needs to run an instance of a different perl script (old.pl). The issue I'm having is that I want to replace all instances of a certain string in the old.pl script without modifying it or having to create a new file with the changes made to it.

So let's say I have this:

```
my $replacementVar = "replace";

my $originalString = "string to be replaced";
```

**do something to replace all instances of the original string with the replacement var**

run the original.pl

Can this be done without modifying the original.pl, as in can I make a temporary change to the string when I run it so that the string reverts back to it's default value after it's done running?

I should note that I can't go in and change any of the code for original.pl

Comment: A lot depends on the contents of `old.pl` and which parts of it need to be changed. Can you show it to us? The obvious solution is to copyit to a new file with the changes in place and execute that file instead. What is the prproblem with this approach?

Comment: the group I'm working with is just looking for a more elegant design. We have a lot of files to work with and we would prefer not to clutter it each time we need a new replacement string. we plan on using new.pl with many different strings

Comment: So have it take a parameter!

Comment: that's the problem, we can't change original.pl to take in an extra parameter :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is to use `eval`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $replacementVar = "replace";
my $originalString = "string to be replaced";
open my $olds, "<", "old.pl" or die("$!");
my $contents = join("", <$olds>);
close $olds;
$contents =~ s/\Q$originalString/$replacementVar/g;
local @ARGV=('param1', 'param2');
eval "$contents; 1" or die $@;
```

Comment: Probably not a problem, but: `$0` will be different. `caller` chain will be different.